# How to represent a binary digital image as a function?

Tags: functions, image-processing

I am trying to represent a binary image as a function.
Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3499191/691717) I want something like this:

[image: dsfs]

I know the correct way is:

[image]

Is it also correct to say a binary image with **m** rows and **n** columns has **N** pixels (**N = mn**), and the function is like below?

[image: dfg]

Or do I have to mention the rows and columns?

Because I only have the number of pixels (`N`) and know nothing about `m` and `n`.

Comment: According to $(1)$, you should mention the rows and columns.  For example, to discuss "part of an image", you need to know what is a "connected subset of the pixels".  In the definition, the symbol $\times$ denotes a Cartesian product, not a numerical product.

Comment: If you just know $N$ then you have a string of $N$ "pixels". This makes sense when you are transmitting a linear text, each letter consuming $8$ pixels in this string. But an image is a two-dimensional display. This means that the $N$ pixels are not just "ordered in line". The "index set" has the structure $[m]\times[n]$, and this structure has to be embedded in the chosen codification.

Comment: I understand. Since it's 2-dimensional data, it is not possible to ignore the indices.